# How to make transparent window in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using the following code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56431991/making-background-transparent) , I have set the camera to solid color (0,0,0,0), but I can't get a transparent window. Any help would be apreciated. Thankyou very much!

```
int fWidth = Screen.width;
int fHeight = Screen.height;
var margins = new MARGINS() { cxLeftWidth = -1 };
var hwnd = GetActiveWindow();
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 0, 255, 2);// Transparency=51=20%, LWA_ALPHA=2
SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, fWidth, fHeight, 32 | 64); //SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020 (32); //SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040 (64)
DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hwnd, ref margins);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try lowering the alpha value to 0.

Comment: I have tried, it doesn't work.